# Preseeding No physical volume defined in volume group

Tags: partitioning, uefi, encryption, lvm

A couple of weeks ago I asked about configuring Ubuntu preseed to configure LVM partitions.  I got no response to that one.

I was able to figure out how to get logical volumes defined for UEFI within a preseed file for Ubuntu 16.04 desktop.  Now I'm trying to set up the physical volume on which the root logical volume (/) resides.  I don't expect an answer, but I have to try.  :)

The following d-i directives in my preseed file work for configuring LVM and all of my filesystems on an UEFI based virtual machine.

```
# Partitioning
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/default_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt
d-i partman/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman/default_label string gpt

d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string vg00
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select gpt-boot-root-swap
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
    gpt-boot-root-swap ::             \
        512 512 512 fat32             \
            $primary{ }               \
            method{ efi } format{ } . \
        1024 1024 1024 ext2              \
            $primary{ } $bootable{ }  \
            method{ format } format{ } \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext2 } \
            mountpoint{ /boot } .                \
        1000 1000 1000000000 ext4                \
            $defaultignore{ }                    \
            $primary{ }                          \
            method{ lvm } \
            device{ /dev/sda } \
            vg_name{ vg00 } \
            . \
        1024 3072 10240 ext4 \
            $lvmok{ } \
            in_vg{ vg00 } lv_name{ lv_root } \
            method{ format } format{ }           \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
            mountpoint{ / } .                    \
        1024 1024 1000000000 ext4                \
            $lvmok{ }                          \
            $defaultignore{ }                    \
            in_vg{ vg00 } lv_name{ lv_delete } \
            .

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

I've been trying to add encryption to /dev/sda3, which is the physical volume associated with the vg00 volume group on which lv_root is created.  I have added the following directives into the preseed file

```
d-i partman-auto/method string crypto
d-i partman-crypto/create/partitions select /dev/sda3
d-i partman-crypto/keytype select passphrase
d-i partman-crypto/keyhash select sha512
d-i partman-crypto/keysize select 512
d-i partman-crypto/cipher select aes-xts-plain64
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase string ThisIsATest
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase-again string ThisIsATest
```

I found the above by piecing together bits and pieces I able to put together by doing web searches.

As an aside, Canonical, if Ubuntu is really your bread and butter, why don't you have better documentation?  Everything I have found has been from places other than any Ubuntu website.

I know there are things missing, but I do not know what those d-i directives would be.  For example, what is the d-i partman-crypto directive to name the encrypted volume?  I'm sure that's needed here.  I'm sure that is why when I try to boot off of my custom ISO I eventually get the error message

```
No physical volume defined in volume group
The automatic partitioning recipe contains the definition of a
volume group that does not contain any physical volume.
Please check the automatic partitioning recipe
```

Like I said at the beginning, I do not expect anyone to answer this question since it's even more niche than my automatic partitioning LVM preseeding question, but I have to try.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: This isn't a niche question. It's a perfectly reasonable thing to do on servers and is common with CentOS. I share your sentiments that Ubuntu's server-side docs are really lacking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you fix it?

```
d-i partman/early_command                         string \
vgs --separator=: --noheadings | cut -f1 -d: | while read vg ; do vgchange -an $vg ; done ; \
pvs --separator=: --noheadings | cut -f1 -d: | while read pv ; do pvremove -ff -y $pv ; done ; \
mdadm --detail --scan | cut -f2 -d' ' | while read array ; do umount -l $array ; done ; \
mdadm --detail --scan | cut -f2 -d' ' | while read array ; do mdadm --stop $array ; done ; \
mdadm --detail --scan | cut -f2 -d' ' | while read array ; do mdadm --remove $array ; done ; \
fdisk -l | grep 'Disk /dev/sd' | cut -f1 -d: | cut -f2 -d' ' | while read disk ; do mdadm --zero-superblock $disk ; done ; \
fdisk -l | grep 'Disk /dev/nvme' | cut -f1 -d: | cut -f2 -d' ' | while read disk ; do mdadm --zero-superblock $disk ; done ; \
fdisk -l | grep 'Disk /dev/sd' | cut -f1 -d: | cut -f2 -d' ' | while read disk ; do dd if=/dev/zero of=$disk bs=1M count=512 ; done ;
fdisk -l | grep 'Disk /dev/nvme' | cut -f1 -d: | cut -f2 -d' ' | while read disk ; do dd if=/dev/zero of=$disk bs=1M count=512 ; done ;
fdisk -l | grep 'Disk /dev/nvme' | cut -f1 -d: | cut -f2 -d' ' | while read disk ; do parted -s $disk mklabel gpt; done
# Partitioning
d-i   partman-auto/method string lvm

# If one of the disks that are going to be automatically partitioned
# contains an old LVM configuration, the user will normally receive a
# warning. Preseed this away
d-i     partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true

# And the same goes for the confirmation to write the lvm partitions.
d-i     partman-lvm/confirm boolean true

# Really, please don't prompt me!
d-i     partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
# auto method must be lvm
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false

# Keep that one set to true so we end up with a UEFI enabled
# system. If set to false, /var/lib/partman/uefi_ignore will be touched
d-i partman-efi/non_efi_system boolean true

# enforce usage of GPT - a must have to use EFI!
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/default_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt
d-i partman/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman/default_label string gpt
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name                  string vg_root

d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select boot-root-all
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
boot-root-all :: \
1024 1024 1024 free \
$iflabel{ gpt } \
$reusemethod{ } \
method{ efi } \
format{ } \
. \
1024 1024 1024 ext2 \
$defaultignore{ } \
method{ format } format{ } \
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext2 } \
mountpoint{ /boot } \
. \
51200 51200 51200 xfs \
$lvmok{ } \
method{ format } format{ } \
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ xfs } \
mountpoint{ / } \
. \
10240 10240 10240 xfs \
$lvmok{ } \
method{ format } format{ } \
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ xfs } \
mountpoint{ /home } \
. \
10240 10240 10240 xfs \
$lvmok{ } \
method{ format } format{ } \
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ xfs } \
mountpoint{ /tmp } \
. \
1 1 -1 xfs                             \
        $lvmok{ }                   \
        method{ format } format{ }              \
        use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ xfs }    \
        label{ liveperson }                            \
        mountpoint{ /test }                      \
.
```

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately without any explaining text is is unclear if your post suggests a solution or if you want to express a similar problem. Please [edit] your answer to clarify if it is intended as an actual answer.

Comment: It seems like the `#` comments in the file are intended as explanation. It seems this is intended as an answer. Still, some clarification/additional explanation of the commands would be very helpful.